# remove blank spaces in drop down list Visual Studios

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

Ok I have a table called DVD_Information and I have a column in the table called Category.
I wish to populate the drop down but due to the table sometimes having more data in the column next to Category the drop down has some blank spaces.
I know it is possible to prevent this as I have had it before but I cant seem to get it to work., any idea's?

**Query**

```
SELECT [Category] FROM [DVD_Infomation]
```

**Screen Shot of what is happing**

[image]

Comment: what type of application is this?

Comment: guess it doesn't matter, the select distinct should do it. You could also do a where category is not empty or null whatever is in the empty space in the DB.

Comment: Thank you. I was not thinking. been a long day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT DISTINCT Category FROM DVD_Information`

[SQL SELECT DISTINCT Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

Comment: A good rule of thumb is if you have to add "Distinct" to your query, you're doing something wrong. For example, you should have a separate table called DVD_Category or something like that, and then just do `select category_name from DVD_Category`

Comment: @msm8bball Agreed. Storing these as literals is poor design and this is just one code smell. Weird that I would get downvoted for it, though.

Comment: I agree with you guys, usually I would But I just need one table with 3 rows category, Director and year and people would only add data to it once a year or two, so as for this very small part I have used DISTINCT.

Answer (score 3):

> "the table sometimes having more data in the column next to Category"

Do you mean there are rows where the Category column is empty? You could try filtering those results:

```
SELECT Category FROM DVD_Infomation WHERE Category IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: However this could result in duplicate entries.